# Computing the minimum distance between each pain of points

Tags: euclidean-distance, minimax

I am trying to read an algorithm for computing minimum distance between each pair of points  from the book: Algorithm Design

[Algorithm Design](https://theswissbay.ch/pdf/Gentoomen%20Library/Algorithms/Algorithm%20Design%20-%20John%20Kleinberg%20-%20%C3%89va%20Tardos.pdf)

[image: Description of Algorithm]

It considers the points in a line. If the points are in a line why we need to sort them? We can start from the beginning and compute the distances from starting pint to  all the points on the  right.

Some body please guide me why we need sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the points are $[4,1,10,11]$.  The distance from the starting point (whether you interpret that as $4$ or $1$) to each other point does not give you the nearest pair of points.

In this problem, the input is an array containing numbers, not in sorted order.